# How can i cancel sending retries?

Tags: api, mailgun

How can i stop\cancel sending retries with API?

Example:

> Will retry in 14400 seconds: postmaster@{my-domain-name} → {recipient-address} 'Subject text' No MX for {recipient-domain} Server response: 498 No MX for {recipient-domain}

Mailgun tries to deliver message to this recipient and increases time range between tries.

Comment: P.S. Retry limit exists, but it would be nice to have a possibility to do that myself.